# Fresh install of Express.js, what port does it listen to?

Tags: node.js

Installed an Express app via the generator. I noticed there is no command in the app.js file that says which port it is listening on, though the official tutorial says its 3000? Tried it, didn't work. Then I added a custom line to tell it what port should it listen to.

Then I gen an error message which is the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOgai.jpg

I have the latest version of npm and node.js installed.

Comment: The one you set

Comment: I set it, then I get that long error log.

Comment: Perhaps show us the code and then we can help you

Comment: Its there on the imgur link.

Comment: Your error log looks like you haven't startet any script. You pointed directly on your project folder not the script to run.

Comment: I used the command "npm start"

Comment: Yes pls provide code and add resources like the log as text in your post, too,

Comment: Magic! I had to use port 5000 seems like 3000 didnt work. Sorry. prblm fixed

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the instructions on the [Express Application Generator page](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html), then in the directory the `express --view=pug myapp` command creates, you should look at the `/bin/www` file.

On line 15 it says:
`var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');`